# Emitting signal from callback

Tags: qt, callback, midi, signals-slots

I am using [RtMidi](https://github.com/thestk/rtmidi) library to handle midi message in my *Qt* application and I am facing problem with slot trigger:

My *PhMidiInput* object is emiting signal from the *RtMidi* callback upon specific midi message but the slots are not always triggered.

Here is a part of the *PhMidiInput* class:

```
class PhMidiInput : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void PhMidiInput() {}
signals:
    void quarterFrame(unsigned char data);
private:
    static void callback(double, std::vector< unsigned char > *message, void *userData ) {
        PhMidiInput *midiInput = (PhMidiInput*)userData;
        if(midiInput)
            midiInput->onMessage(message);
    }

    void onMessage(std::vector<unsigned char> *message) {
        ...
        emit quarterFrame(data);
        ...
    }

}
```

Connecting to a lambda functor works:

```
PhMidiInput midiIn;
int quarterFrameCount;

connect(&midiIn, &PhMidiInput::quarterFrame, [&](unsigned char data) {
    quarterFrameCount++;
});
```

Connecting to my application window works to:

```
// MyWindow inherits from QMainWindow
connect(_midiIn, &PhMidiInput::quarterFrame, this, &MyWindow::onQuarterFrame);
```

When trying to connect to a custom class (*MidiTest*) inheriting from *QObject* it does'nt trigger:

```
connect(_midiIn, &PhMidiInput::quarterFrame, this, &MidiTest::onQuarterFrame);
```

I was wondering if there was something around [QObject::moveToThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread) but since I don't create the thread myself (the signal is sent from a callback) I don't know if I need to use it or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as calling `emit obj->quarterFrame(data);` from the callback. If the connection type is default then this will be perfectly thread safe.

Though you should create a `QByteArray` from `data` to pass around as `data` will likely not be valid by the time the slots get called.

```
void callback(..., void* user){
    //user is the standard void* in most callbacks passed as reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)
    unsigned char* data = ...;
    QByteArray bytes(data);
    emit reinterpret_cast<PhMidiInput>(user)->quarterFrame(bytes);//calling the signal which will behave as you'd expect

}
```

Comment: In fact *data* is a simple *unsigned char*. The signal is emitted from a method called by the callback. I will add the missing code.

Comment: @MartinDelille sorry I thought I saw a `*` in there

Answer (score 0):

In the last `connect()` call you pass `this` and `MidiTest::onQuarterFrame` as the receiver object and method. I bet `this` is not an instance of `MidiTest`, is it?

The problem here is that you're passing SLOT method from `MidiTest`, while the receiver object is `this`, which is not instance of `MidiTest`. Change receiver from `this` to some instance of `MidiTest`.

I'm surprised this code doesn't crash your application when running.

Comment: Yes *this* is a *MidiTest* class instance in the third case (and a *MyWindow* class instance in the second case.